# In this situation what should be the correct argument for direction of current?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]
First of all consider such a system, in which there's a square loop which is going out of the magnetic field,

thereby an EMF will induce, and B will be at positive potential while A will be at negative potential.

Now as we know by Fleming's right hand rule the current direction will be in anticlockwise direction, but my doubt why the current will not flow from B to A in the wire which is connected between A and B, even though B is at higher potential?

Comment: What do you mean that current won't flow? It will?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I mean to ask that why will the current not flow from B to A as B is at higher potential

Comment: Im expecting that the current will flow. I am asking why you don't think that the current will flow. Also, I think you got it wrong. The current direction should be clockwise. B is at lower voltage.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that B is at higher potential than A.  In fact, the idea of potential does not apply to emf caused by a changing magnetic flux.  However, the emf is real and is directed clockwise.  Lenz's law tells you that: the magnetic flux is into the page but decreasing as the loop leaves the field.  The emf will therefore tend to set up a magnetic field into the page, to oppose the change in flux.  Thus current would flow clockwise.

Why doesn't potential make sense here?  Suppose B were at higher potential than A.  Current would then flow from B to A.  But there are two opposite ways that could happen, and only one way that a net current can actually flow around this loop, unless you believe that B is a source of charge and A is a sink (neither can be true, as there's nothing special about either point).

Comment: Just to be clear: potential applies irrotational fields, that is they are a gradient of a potential.  Here, the curl of E is not zero, so the would be potential difference btw two points is path dependent, and thus ill defined